# aligning linear layout half the size of screen in exact center of screen horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Title of question says it all, I am trying to make a view like shown, here center part should be exactly half size of the screen and should be present at center of screen.[image: the sketch of my view]

I am using layout_weight and weightsum and avoid padding left and right:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/OuterlinLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4" >
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/GlobalLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >contens of main view</LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

But it is not showing what i wanted...what is the mistake that i am making?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your OuterlinLayout `LinearLayout` should have `android:orientation="horizontal"` instead of vertical and all its children should have `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: thanx...i know that was a silly question but thanx for answering